# dd/mm/YYYY format date - while loop problems adding 1 day

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am creating a while loop in PHP to iterate through all the days between two dates.

```
$startdate = "17/12/2022"; // my dd/mm/YYYY format start date
$startdate = str_replace('/', '-',$startdate); // convert the slashes to dashes to signify european date format
$startdate = strtotime($startdate); // convert the date into a date object
$enddate = "16/12/2023"; // my dd/mm/YYYY format start date
$enddate = str_replace('/', '-',$enddate); // convert the slashes to dashes to signify european date format
$enddate = strtotime($enddate); // convert the date into a date object

echo(date('d/m/Y',$startdate)."<br/>");
echo(date('d/m/Y',$enddate)."<br/>");

while($startdate <= $enddate) {
    $dayofweek = date('w',$startdate); // a task
    echo($dayofweek)."<br/>");
    //I need to increment the $startdate by one day here?
}
?>
```

I believe that changing the slashes to dashes effectively instructs PHP to recognise the date as dd/mm/YYYY rather than mm/dd/YYYY. There are references (in many examples) to the PHP documentation outlining this functionality but the PHP documentation no longer shows this; nor does it show that it is depleted or has been changed. It is simply omitted. My tests show that it works but I cannot find reference to an alternative.

I then convert both dates to a date object using `strtotime` so that they can be compared.

I then need to add 1 day to the `$startdate` and loop, but it is the adding one day that is foxing me.
All the examples I can find are using todays date or a string not formatted dd/mm/YYYY.

I freely admit that I may have got the whole premise wrong but any pointers for good practise would be appreciated.

Comment: `I believe that`...why do you believe that, exactly? Please point to the area in the documentation or other reliable source, and/or observed behaviour

Comment: The PHP documentation used to have `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed`. I can't find that anymore

Comment: But that aside, why not just use an unambiguous date format such as YYYY-MM-DD to begin with? If you need to use something in a user-supplied data format that you can't control, just parse it using https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php and then proceed as normal

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Could you also tell us what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to walk through all the days from start date to end date? Do you really want to do this in Unix timestamps?

Comment: Using the DateTime class is much easier. You can [modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) your date by adding a single day to it, and it will also compare much easier

Comment: ADyson,"I believe" because I have seen it in referenced in answers on StackOverflow but I cannot find it in the PHP documentation despite references to it. Not only that but my own tests confirm it is the case.

Comment: @arresteddevelopment as anyber says, this seems to have been removed from the documentation for some reason, so fair enough that you can't find it. I guess maybe it's to encourage people to use a more formal, usable and flexible way of parsing dates using createFromFormat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `DateTime` class and the `DateInterval` Class and the `DatePeriod` class you get quite a bit of the heavy lifting done for you

```
$startdate = "17/12/2022"; // my dd/mm/YYYY format start date
$enddate = "31/12/2022"; // my dd/mm/YYYY format start date

$sDate = ( new Datetime() )->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $startdate);
$eDate = ( new Datetime() )->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $enddate);

$oneDay = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($sDate, $oneDay ,$eDate);

foreach ( $daterange as $dat) {
    echo $dat->format('d/m/y - w D') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULTS using a smaller range of dates

```
17/12/22 - 6 Sat
18/12/22 - 0 Sun
19/12/22 - 1 Mon
20/12/22 - 2 Tue
21/12/22 - 3 Wed
22/12/22 - 4 Thu
23/12/22 - 5 Fri
24/12/22 - 6 Sat
25/12/22 - 0 Sun
26/12/22 - 1 Mon
27/12/22 - 2 Tue
28/12/22 - 3 Wed
29/12/22 - 4 Thu
30/12/22 - 5 Fri
```

Comment: Every day is a school day. I have been through this solution's syntax and can see how it works. You are absolutely correct that the correct classes can be used very effectively. It helps to see them applied in context. I will be using them from now on.